# why fiona gives error while importing geopandas ?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, importerror, geopandas, fiona

I am trying to import geopandas. 
I have installed Fiona, gdal separately, and added path to osgeo before executing pip install geopandas. 
However, when I try to import geopandas on my jupyternotebook, it gives me error saying below.

**ImportError: cannot import name 'urlparse' from 'fiona.compat' (C:\Users\me\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fiona\compat.py)**

Im using python3.7 with jupyternotebook anaconda3, and windows10. 
Does anyone know why this error happens?

Comment: Since you are using Anaconda, I would recommend to install geopandas with `conda` instead of with `pip`.